# How to sort items such that I waste the least amount of space possible on each row of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, uicollectionview

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Assume we know this info about our collectionView items and the max width of each row:

```
let maxRowWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40//the width of the screen minus the collectionView insets

let items = [(text: "Lululemon", width: 98.955), (text: "boots", width: 67.47), (text: "sweaters", width: 89.61), (text: "Gymshark", width: 96.72), (text: "Free People", width: 110.325), (text: "dress", width: 66.18), (text: "air force 1", width: 93.53999999999999), (text: "Athleta", width: 77.205), (text: "dresses", width: 81.6), (text: "Brandy Melville", width: 131.49), (text: "Princess Polly", width: 121.41), (text: "formal dress", width: 111.88499999999999), (text: "jeans", width: 65.265), (text: "booties", width: 79.365), (text: "Ray-Ban", width: 84.78), (text: "cheetah print", width: 117.61500000000001), (text: "skirt", width: 57.975), (text: "mom jeans", width: 102.31499999999998), (text: "Revolve", width: 82.57499999999999), (text: "Patagonia", width: 96.27)]
let horizontalSpaceBetweenItems:CGFloat = 9
```

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that will allow me to sort the items in a way that will allow me to minimize the amount of white space for each row. For example, in the screenshot, if I swapped "jeans" with "These Three Boutique", then the 4th line would have less whitespace.

How can I find the permutation of the `items` array such that there is the least amount of empty space in the collectionView?

I'm sure there is an applicable algorithm for this scenario, but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the bin packing problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Your rows are essentially bins of fixed volume and you are looking to achieve the minimal set of bins possible.

Comment: I actually don't care about the number of bins used-- I want each bin (however many it may be) to be as full as possible. The results may be similar in practice though, so I'll try this and see how well it works

Comment: So you want them all to be as close to equal length as possible? In other words, you don't want the last line to only have a single item because there is a lot of whitespace there?

Comment: If the last row is the only one with a lot of whitespace, then that's fine. The more I think about it, the bin-packing problem should actually work fine as long as I make sure the least full rows are shown last. I'm just trying to solve the problem of excessive whitespace in the middle rows because it looks bad